# Haskell get divisors efficiently

Tags: haskell

I want to efficiently find the proper divisors of an integer n.

How can I do this?

For now I´m using the following function

```
divisors :: (Integral a) => a -> [a]
divisors n = filter ((0 ==) . (n `mod`)) [1 .. (n `div` 2)]
```

But I have read that it is more efficient when I only check for the numbers until the square root of n. Have you got any suggestions how to solve it with the square root?

Comment: Your current function checks all numbers up to half of `n`, and you want to change it so it checks up to the square root of `n` instead? I'm pretty confident that you can work out for yourself how to change your function to do that.

Answer (score -1):

Given a number *n* is dividable by *k*, then *n/k* is a divisor of *n* as well. Indeed, since *n/(n/k)=k*. If *k>√n*, we thus know that *k/n<√n*, and therefore, instead of calculating all the divisors, we can each time we find a divisor, yield the "co-divisor" as well.

We thus can implement the algorithm as follows:

```
divisors :: Integral a => a -> [a]
divisors n = concatMap f (filter ((==) 0 . mod n) (takeWhile (\k -> k*k <= n) [1 .. n]))
    where f k | k < l = [k, l]
              | otherwise = [k]
              where l = div n k
```

Here we thus first use `takeWhile (\k -> k*k <= n) [1 .. n]` to create a list from `1` until (and including if it is integral) `√n`).

Next we filter these elements, and only retain those that divide `n`. Finally for each of these elements, we check if the co-divisor is different. If that is the case, we both yield `k` and the co-divisor `l`, otherwise (this will only be the case for `√n`), we only yield `k`.

For example:

```
Prelude Data.List> divisors 1425
[1,1425,3,475,5,285,15,95,19,75,25,57]
```